# Numeric check of string not always working as expected

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I have an issue, that I cannot resolve by myself. I am reading string values from a file in CSV-format with default encoding (UTF-8 as far as I know). The thing is, that I use the following method to determine if the strings contains digits only:

```
private static bool IsDigitsOnly(string str)
    {
        return str.All(Char.IsDigit);
    }
```

In mostly all cases it´s is working fine, but it returns 'false' when the input string is one of the following:

- 726849004
- 704152104
- 779450251
- 779459121
- 346751902
- 779459111
- 779459115
- 779428100
- 726852040

I tried with another approach by changing the method to this:

```
str.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9');
```

It does the same in the cases above.

When I debug, I can see, that the string values are correct (no trailing or leading whitespaces, chars or anything)

Can someone help me out here?

Thank you in advance,
Thomas.

Comment: My guess is there is some whitespace in there, try calling `Trim()` before checking.

Comment: I would start from checking for which chars this condition is not valid. Maybe some chars only looks like digits, but have a different utf-8 code.

Comment: James: I already do trim the strings for whitespaces and tabs. When debugging I can see, that the parameter string contains nothing else than characters.

Konrad Kokosa:
I will try that, thanks

Comment: @thbaan well if that's the case then next port of call would be making sure the data is being read in correctly. You mentioned you *believe* the data is in UTF-8 format, however, perhaps it's not and you are reading the data using the wrong encoding? You can check this by opening it using a tool like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or just by opening the file in normal notepad & attempting to save (it should select the current file format by default).

Comment: Also, have you checked to see if there is possibly an EOL char on the string? Given these are coming from a CSV file there is a good chance (if the string is at the end).

Comment: @James the file I am reading is generated by Magento, which should be using UTF-8 encoding (without 'bom', it says?). I haven't specified any encoding in the StreamReader, but it should be using UTF-8 as default. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: BOM just means "byte-order mark" and it shouldn't *really* make a difference here. Yeah, if you don't say otherwise the default should be UTF-8 (you can verify that by checking the `CurrentEncoding` property of the reader). Sounds like your problem is Magenta is using a [unit separator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_separator#Field_separators) which you haven't taken into account, just remove it.

Comment: Thanks @James! The strange thing is, that it´s only 9 of totally 120.000 lines in the CSV-file that causes this problem. I have added '(char)31' to the array of chars that i used in the Trim() method, which seems to have solved the problem (for now :) )

Comment: @thbaan the good news is it's not an issue with your code, the ideal solution would be to get in touch with the 3rd party and have them correct the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve this and found that there is some skeptic character at the end of each string except for 3rd and 4th. See my test app screen shot:
[image]

This is causing the error. If you see the ASCII value of this character then its 31, listed as  Unit Separator. Need to look why it's there.

I know that I am not answering your question but trying to give/get some pointer to solve this interesting problem.

Comment: Did you copy the test data from the question or manually type it? If you copied it then, yeah, there is a good chance there will be non-ASCII chars in there.

Comment: Actually you are right. I just changed the method, so I could see every char instead of checking the whole string at once, and what I didn't expect was, that there were acually 10 chars in the string instead of 9 (which are visible). When I count the chars by str.Count() it also returns 10. So thank you for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: So, are you able to remove the 10th character?

Comment: Well - I could remove the character by its ASCII value (31) - but I don't know if the issue is caused by wrong encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
return str.All(char.IsDigit);
```

with

```
return str.All(c =>
    char.IsDigit(c));
```

and set a breakpoint on the second line, then debug to inspect which characters are being passed and hopefully find the one which isn't a digit.